# Is it possible that App works on TestFlight but fails when released?

Tags: ios, restore, testflight, in-app

I rewrite the codes of restoring purchased, and because it could not be tested in sandbox, I tested the app on TestFlight.

The app worked fine both on purchasing and restoring. And yesterday the app was passed and released to public, I also downloaded it and tested it again, but I found it fails to work on both purchasing and restoring.

Today, I upload the same codes with new build to TestFlight and test again, the app works fine.

Is it possible?

P.S. I use the same email on TestFlight account and Apple ID on iPhone.

```
func requestProductData()
{

    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: self.productIdentifiers as Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        self.activity.stopAnimating()
        self.activity.hidden = true

        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Setting"
        alert.message = "In-App Purchases Not Enabled, Please enable In App Purchase in Settings"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alert.show()

    }
}

func restorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased:
            self.deliverProduct(transaction)
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
            productsList.reloadData()
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Failed:
            print(transaction.error)
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Restored:
            self.deliverProduct(transaction)
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
            break;
        default:
            break
        }

    }

}

func deliverProduct(transaction:SKPaymentTransaction) {

    if transaction.payment.productIdentifier == "com.xxxxx"
    {
        saveData.setBool(true, forKey: "xxxxxPurchased")

    }else if transaction.payment.productIdentifier == "com.xxx"{

        saveData.setBool(true, forKey: "xxxPurchased")

    }

}
```

Update:
The In-Apps have been released and the two products had been purchased before. Every product will show a check mark if they are purchased. I get no check mark on the released version, but get check mark on TestFlight version.

Comment: Can you provide an exact error which you are facing?

Comment: sure. if the in-apps aren't released, the store version doesn't see them

Comment: or if the products are hardcoded, it can't use them

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya I add a check mark on the product which is purchased. I saw no any check mark after purchasing and restoring. I had purchased the two products in the previous version.

Comment: @Daij-Djan The in-apps has been released for two versions, and I had tried to purchase the two products, and they succeeded returning me two check marks before.

Comment: I am not sure Testflight requests the Production Apple Server. As always the IAP doc is not clear https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/AppReview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH10-SW1 maybe you can ask apple in a Technical Request

Comment: @NicolasBraun OK.  Thanks your suggestion.